# Get rid of Mac OS X partition on Dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, macbook-pro, iphone

First time posting on AskUbuntu. I am new to Ubuntu/Linux and I have a MacBook Pro. I have finally got the dual boot to work. My laptop is a little older so it only has a 250Gb hard drive. I am running the 64bit Ubuntu 12.04. I really want to just transition to Ubuntu and get rid of Mac OS X so I can fully immerse myself to learn it. What is holding me back is iTunes. I have a iPhone and I use iTunes to manage my music and what not. I have read a little that Rhythmbox can manage iphone music, but I don't know if it would work with iOS 7. I am trying to learn Linux because I am trying to make it in the information security field and I know a lot of security functions come from Linux.

My question is... How can I make my Mac OS partition smaller (just enough to keep iTunes + my 80gb of music + a little room to keep adding music) and dedicate the new free/unallocated space to my Ubuntu os? I am sure that you would use gpartition to do this, but I have NO IDEA how to do it. Nor do I want to do a fresh install, because it took a while to figure out which drivers I needed to get the Nvidia drivers to work; I have already set up my Ubuntu 12.04 and like my setup. Does anyone have a iPhone and manage the music successfully using Ubuntu?

Hopefully someone on here can help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Boot a LiveUSB, use GParted to decrease the size of you Mac OS X partition and increase your Ubuntu partition.

[Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/) is a guide on resizing.

Answer (score 0):

Novine is correct in general; however, I want to point out one possible pitfall: If you've installed Linux to boot in BIOS mode via Boot Camp, resizing with GParted will cause the [hybrid MBR](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html) to be replaced with a standard protective MBR. This in turn will cause the Mac's firmware to refuse to boot anything in BIOS mode. IMHO, the best long-term solution is to do away with the hybrid MBR and switch to EFI-mode booting. I've got a [Web page describing this configuration,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/ubuntu-efi/) but it's a bit old and describes a lot of stuff you've already done. You basically just need to install rEFInd and an EFI filesystem driver for whatever filesystem holds your Linux kernel, and maybe a `/boot/refind_linux.conf` file. Alternatively, you can regenerate the hybrid MBR with `gdisk` (in OS X or Linux) or `gptsync` (launched from rEFIt or rEFInd).